# Web API custom routes with same name but different HTTP methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

We're trying to implement VersionedRoutes on our API and are declaring our routes in a class as:

```
new VersionedRoute(
    version,
    "GetRiskReports",
    "/Members/{id}/Cpin/RiskReports",
    new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"controller", "Members"},
        {"action", "GetRiskReports"},
        {"id", RouteParameter.Optional}
    }),
new VersionedRoute(
    version,
    "PostRiskReports",
    "/Members/{id}/Cpin/RiskReports",
    new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"controller", "Members"},
        {"action", "PostRiskReports"},
        {"id", RouteParameter.Optional}
    })
```

The controller methods are declared like:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetRiskReports(int id)

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostRiskReports(int id)
```

obviously at the moment, a GET request to the url /Members/123/Cpin/RiskReports routes through to the first route ok, but a POST request fails to route, as it matches the first route but the controller method is marked as GET only. Is there anyway to add the HTTP method to the custom route. The client doesn't want to change the route name.

Answer (score 1):

In your **RouteConfig.cs**, register such config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("GetRiskReports", "Members/{id}/Cpin/RiskReports" ,
      new {
             controller = "Members",
             action = "GetRiskReports"
      },
      new {
            HttpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get)
       }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("PostRiskReports", "Members/{id}/Cpin/RiskReports" ,
      new {
             controller = "Members",
             action = "PostRiskReports"
      },
      new {
            HttpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post)
       }
);
```